# XML output with Filestorage in OpenCV

Tags: c++, xml, opencv, file-io

I want to output an XML file using OpenCV filestorage class. But the output is not same as I want. I need help to write my data in a different format. Following is the Function code.

```
void write_data(int x, int y, int w, int h, int count, int region)
{

    FileStorage fs("data.xml", FileStorage::APPEND);
    fs <<"frame";
    fs << "{" << "number" <<count
    << "}";

    fs << "box";                              
    fs << "{" << "h" << h;
    fs <<        "w" << w;
    fs <<        "xc"  << x;
    fs <<        "yc"  << y 
    << "}";

    fs.release();                                       
    cout << "Write Done." << endl;
}
```

The output is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<opencv_storage>
<frame>
 <number>1</number></frame>
 <box>
    <h>52</h>
    <w>52</w>
    <xc>1156</xc>
    <yc>336</yc></box>
 <!-- resumed -->

<frame>
   <number>1</number></frame>
   <box>
   <h>69</h>
   <w>69</w>
   <xc>1112</xc>
   <yc>376</yc></box>
<!-- resumed -->
```

Following is the desired output. For the value of "confident" I want generate a random number between 0.5000 to 1.0.

```
    <frame number="1">
    <objectlist>
        <object confidence="0.89324">
            <box h="52" w="52" xc="1156" yc="336" />
        </object>
        <object confidence="0.95996">
            <box h="69" w="69" xc="1112" yc="376" />
        </object>
    </objectlist>
</frame>
<frame number="2">
    <objectlist>
        <object confidence="0.89324">
            <box h="42" w="38" xc="521" yc="94" />
        </object>
        <object confidence="0.95996">
            <box h="38" w="39" xc="633" yc="99" />
        </object>
    </objectlist>
</frame>
```

Comment: I don't think you can get the exact same output with OpenCV FileStorages. Do you need a _similar_ format with the same information to be easily saved/loaded with OpenCV? Otherwise you can consider using some XML library, like [TinyXML2](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml2/) or similar

Comment: I want to make it simple as possible using OpenCV filestorage class, If it is not possible then the only way to do it with XML libraries but I have no knowledge about those.

Comment: It can be done with OpenCV, but you won't get the exact structure as your desired output. If you're going to use only your custom structure, there won't be any problem

Comment: I need it in exact structure.

Comment: Or then modify it with XSLT script.

Comment: Then you need an XML library... that won't be difficult, but I don't have time to show you an example.Good luck

Comment: If you find time please help me do it with XML libraries.

Comment: @MazharMohsin - in <a href="http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/old_xml_yaml_persistence.html">this documentation</a> I read "XML attributes inside tags are not supported, aside from the object type specification (type_id attribute)"; I I suggest you to use some XML library

Comment: Could you help me to that with XSLT?